# Unable to exit loop with Sentinal value

Tags: java

I have been trying to exit the loop by using various methods, This is the closest I've gotten but still it has a Scanner mismatch error.

Could someone point out what im missing?

Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LeapYear
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean four ;
        boolean hundred;
        boolean four_hundred;
        boolean quit=true;
        int check= 2000;
        int min=1582;
        String test;

        //System.out.println("Enter a year to check if it  is a leap year");
        do {
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter a year to check if it  is a leap year");
                if(check <min ) {
                    System.out.println("That year is too old, choose a year in more recent history");
                }
                check =input.nextInt();
            } while( check < min);

            // check =input.nextInt();

            if(check % 4==0) {
                four=true;
            } else {
                four=false;
            }

            if(check%100==0) {
                hundred=true;
            } else {
                hundred=false;
            }

            if(check %400==0) {
                four_hundred=true;
            } else {
                four_hundred=false;
            }

            if(four==true) {

                if(four==true&&hundred==false&&four_hundred==false) {
                    System.out.println("The year is a leap year");
                }


                if(four==true&&hundred==true&&four_hundred==false) {
                    System.out.println("The year is not a leap year");
                }

                if(four==true&&hundred==true&&four_hundred==true) {
                    System.out.println("The year is a leap year");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("The year is not a leap year");
            }

            System.out.println("DO YOU WANT TO QUIT: Y/N ?");
            while(!input.hasNext("true|false")) {
                System.out.println("That is neither a true or false.");
                input.nextBoolean();

                if(input.hasNextBoolean()) {
                    quit=true;
                }

                if(input.hasNextBoolean()) {
                    quit=false;
                }
            }
        } while(!quit==false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you make a seperate method that returns true/false for any given input to check for a leap year. It only takes about 5 or 6 lines of code. Also using booleans and `==` is redundant. `if (x == true)` is just `if (x)`, and `x == false && y ==true` is `!x && y`

Comment: I believe the problem exists around `input.nextBoolean();`. You never capture that value and you set the code to quit twice after that regardless of what was entered if the Scanner has two more boolean values

Comment: `!quit == false`?? Is there a reason for writing *anything* like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to improve your code:

1. Improve a names of variables.
2. Remove unused variables.
3. Simplify if statement expressions.

Here is a code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LeapYear
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isFour;
        boolean isQuit = true;
        int checkedYear = 2000;
        int minimumAcceptedYear = 1582;

        //System.out.println("Enter a year to check if it  is a leap year");
        do {
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter a year to check if it is a leap year");
                checkedYear = input.nextInt();
                if ( checkedYear < minimumAcceptedYear ) {
                    System.out.println("That year is too old, choose a year in more recent history");
                }
            } while ( checkedYear < minimumAcceptedYear );

            isFour = (checkedYear % 4) == 0;

            if ( isFour ) {
                System.out.println("The year is a leap year");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The year is not a leap year");
            }

            System.out.println("DO YOU WANT TO QUIT: (true/false) ?");

            if ( input.hasNextBoolean() ) {     
                isQuit = input.nextBoolean();
            } else {
                        System.out.println("That is neither a true or false.");
            }
        } while ( !isQuit );
    }
}
```

This is looks a far better. I would you suggest extract

```
isFour = (checkedYear % 4) == 0;

if ( isFour ) {
    System.out.println("The year is a leap year");
} else {
    System.out.println("The year is not a leap year");
}
```

to another method `isLeapYear` with parameter `aYear`. You has a mismatch error because of you was giving invalid input data after checking is given year too old. You should move if condition below `checkedYear` assigment to avoid these error. I hope that's helpful answer.

Comment: `isQuit = input.nextBoolean();
 if ( isQuit ) isQuit = true;
 else isQuit = false;` The if/else is not necessary as all it does is setting `isQuit` to the same value it already has.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the outer loop a while true loop. Then, when you want to quit, you just return from the method, therefore stopping the method & loop. No need for the quit sentinel value

You also prompt for Y/N, so you should check for that, not true or false.

```
String q = "n";
do {
  System.out.println("Do you want to quit: Y/N ?");
  String q = input.next();
  if (q.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) return; // quit right here 
  else if (!q.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
  {
      System.out.println("That is neither a y or n.");
      continue; // repeat
  } else { } // entered y, so continue on with the outer loop 
} while (!q.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || !q.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));
```

---

And general tip. Writing this pattern is a very beginner thing to do, and it may look nice and easy to understand

```
if(check %400==0) {
    four_hundred=true;
} else { 
    four_hundred=false;
}
```

But, you really should just write like so

```
four_hundred = check % 400;
```

---

and here, why get four is true inside the condition where you are guaranteed its value?

```
if(four==true) {
    if(four==true&&hundred==false&&four_hundred==false) {
        System.out.println("The year is a leap year");
    }
    if(four==true&&...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code that would explain why you cannot exit the loop.

```
System.out.println("DO YOU WANT TO QUIT: Y/N ?");
while(!input.hasNext("true|false")) {
    System.out.println("That is neither a true or false.");
    input.nextBoolean();

    if(input.hasNextBoolean()) {
        quit=true;
    }

    if(input.hasNextBoolean()) {
        quit=false;
    }
}
```

With `input.nextBoolean();` you read the input but there are two issues:

1. an `InputMismatchException` will be thrown if the input cannot be scanned into `true` or `false`
2. you consume the input but do not put it into a variable

Ignoring the first issue for the moment, the problem is that then try to set `quit` based on another check of the input. This means that `input.hasNextBoolean()` can only be `true` if the user enters true or false one more time.

Aside from this while loop, there is also a problem with the outer most do/while

```
    ...
} while(!quit==false);
```

You are testing *not* `quit` and stay in the loop if it is `false`. This means that when `quit == true` you stay in the loop.

You probably want to write `while (!quit)`.